# Move enemies in platform game

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Im relative new to as3, this is my first question here.

Im making super mario game, I added tiles, collision detection, enemies, scrolling.

Sorry for my english, if you dont understand me well, I uploaded file here that you can understand better.

http://www.fastswf.com/K0pTu_0

When game starts all enemies are moving, what I want is that enemies move only if they are on the stage, or if they are near the player.
For example if I set enemy position enemy.x = 3000;
I dont want that he moves if player.x = 40 or something like that.

I tried something like this

```
 if (enemy.x < stage.stageWidth)
 {
 enemy.x +=  enemy.speed;
 }
```

But when enemy left the stage, he just stop and wont move anymore.

Btw, I crated one movie clip and I put everything inside it including player.
For example I scroll MovieClip to left, and character go right.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider a pre-made platform. This has a free version that you can use to help develop something similar to what you are working on. The paid version has some nice features as well.

https://www.scirra.com/construct2

Comment: Thank you for your offere, but Im interested only in programming.

Comment: Ok guys I was tired when I asked this question :)

Comment: I solved this, I used only enemy.x and player.x. Enemy will only move if its not too far of the player. I mean if the distance between enemy and player is not big.

Comment: if (enemy.x - player.x < 600)
{
 enemy will move or shoot
}